# How switch to other store view in Magento?

Tags: magento

I have Create another Website , Store and Store view in magento.
[image]
Now I don't know what is the link to the other store view.I want the link or a store switcher that worked well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this tutorial. This may be helpful for you.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/multi-store_set_up/multiple_website_setup_with_different_document_roots

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/

Answer (score 3):

You can easily change the storeview via link with the param ___store=

Like: example.com/?___store=french